# Export whole Projekt to multiple geotiff

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export

I want to export my whole Projekt (with the current activated Layers) to multiple geoTIFF's. Each TIFF images should be have a dimension of 1km x 1km. My project consists polygons out of a shapefile. So in principle like many screenshots with 1km x 1km saved in geoTIFF's.

How does it work?

Comment: What software is your project in?

Comment: QGIS 3.6.1 on Win10 64-bit

Comment: I've added the `qgis` tag. There's still a few unknowns with your task - for example how do you define the bounds of your project, what resolution do you want your geoTIFFs to be, and what scale you want them. If you can edit your question with some more information, and maybe some concrete numbers (eg "my project region covers the whole of Liechtenstein and I want 800x800 pixel geoTIFFs for each 1km^2") that would help.